# password_get_info returning unexpected results

Tags: php, docker, hash, passwords, kirby

Usually, you can use `password_get_info($string);` to get some information about a hashed password which will return something like this:

```
[
    'algo' => int,
    'algoName' => 'name of algorithm|unknown',
    'options' => [/*options for algo, or empty if unknown */]
]
```

If the string isn't a hash, you'll get a result like this:

```
[
    'algo' => 0,
    'algoName' => 'unknown',
    'options' => []
]
```

Some widespread authentication methods are build around this.

What I'm experiencing right now is, that I'm getting the following result where the value for `algo` is `NULL` instead of the usual `0`:

```
[
    'algo' => NULL,
    'algoName' => 'unknown',
    'options' => []
]
```

Now the problem ist, that I can't figure out why it's returning `NULL` instead of `0` which breaks the package that handles authentication in the project I'm building. Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

For reference, I'm running the official `php:7.4-apache` Docker image with PHP 7.4.3.

Comment: Provide the hash which causes this.

Comment: I cannot replicate, can you show us what you hashed that returned this info?

Comment: Also take into consideration that `password_get_info` gets info about hash, generated by `password_hash` function, and not by any other hashing methods like `mcrypt` or whatever.